# I need an email sent on a specific date/time. Query needs to pop data ext. 1 day before date/time

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation

I need an email sent on a specific date, my current query populates a data extension from the difference of days since the users received a particular "email id". What would be the best way to have this query populate a new data ext 1 day before the given date?

```
SELECT 
  EmailAddress as SubscriberKey
  , EmailAddress
  , first_name
  , last_name
  , registration_date 
FROM Wild_Spirit_12pm h 
WHERE h.EmailAddress IN (
   SELECT s.SubscriberKey   
   FROM _Sent s     
   INNER JOIN _Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID   
   WHERE j.EmailID = '2457224'
   AND DATEDIFF(Day, s.EventDate, Getdate()) = 1) /* this is where i need it send 1 day before 6/28/16 */
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a SOQL query. Please provide more context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?  Casting the dates as `date` will set the time portion to midnight.

```
SELECT 
  h.EmailAddress as SubscriberKey
  , h.EmailAddress
  , h.first_name
  , h.last_name
  , h.registration_date 
FROM Wild_Spirit_12pm h 
WHERE h.EmailAddress IN (
   SELECT s.SubscriberKey   
   FROM _Sent s     
   INNER JOIN _Job j ON (s.JobID = j.JobID)
   WHERE j.EmailID = 2457224 /* emailid is a number */
   AND DATEDIFF(d, cast(s.EventDate as date), cast(Getdate() as date)) = 1 /* was yesterday*/
)
```

or a more sargable version:

```
SELECT 
  h.EmailAddress as SubscriberKey
  , h.EmailAddress
  , h.first_name
  , h.last_name
  , h.registration_date 
FROM Wild_Spirit_12pm h 
WHERE h.EmailAddress IN (
   SELECT s.SubscriberKey   
   FROM _Sent s     
   INNER JOIN _Job j ON (s.JobID = j.JobID)
   WHERE j.EmailID = 2457224 /* emailid is a number */
   AND s.eventDate >= convert(date, getDate()-1) 
   and s.eventDate < convert(date, getDate())
)
```

Comment: so the only way i could set the date to any of my choosing would be to put this query in an automation set to run on that specific date correct? or is there  a way to hardcode the date(6/28/16) directly into the query?

Comment: You can hardcode the date if you want.   Instead of `cast(getDate() as date)` you can use `cast('2016-06-23' as date)`.

Comment: Sweet. Did this work for you?  If so, would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: there you buddy! thanks for being a great help to the community!

Comment: Hey Adam, I tried the date query between two dates and i keep getting this error, maybe you can help. trying to create a year to date field in a DE. http://i.imgur.com/mxBRHBb.png                                                                                            This line causes the error :                                                                                                                     (select count(*)  from TenWays_0 where DATEDIFF(Day, Getdate(), EventDate) BETWEEN DATEDIFF(Day, Getdate(), '2016-01-01') AND DATEDIFF(Day, Getdate(), '2016-12-31')) as EOY. thank you!

Comment: Please post it in a new question.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs, what is `date` in `convert(date, getDate())` ?

Comment: It's a datatype -- a datetime without the time